# Laravel: the save method doesn't work in the booted function

Tags: laravel

I want to create or update a slug attribute whenever an object is created or updated.
For the initial creation of the object I can't use the creating event as I need the object id.
So I finally put my slug code in the saved event as it works for both create and update actions.
But it looks like the save method in the booted function causes my browser to load forever.

```
class Discussion extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    ...


    protected static function booted(): void
    {   
        static::saved(function (Discussion $discussion) {
            $discussion->slug = Str::slug($discussion->subject, '-').'-'.$discussion->id;
            $discussion->save();   // <= This causes the browser loading forever.
        }); 

        static::deleting(function (Discussion $discussion) {
            $discussion->groups()->detach();
            $discussion->registrations()->delete();
        }); 
    }   
}
```

It finally ended up with this error: `child process still did not exit sending a sigterm` and I had to reboot my server.

Anyway, it's clear the probleme comes from the save method.
So I'm wondering how can I save the slug value if the save method doesn't work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are registering an event to trigger whenever the model is saved AND you save the model in that event, creating a loop. Try saving without events:

```php
static::saved(function (Discussion $discussion) {
  $discussion->slug = Str::slug($discussion->subject, '-').'-'.$discussion->id;
  $discussion->saveQuietly();   // <= This does NOT causes the browser loading forever.
});
```